# QTableWidget selected rows column information needed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget, which displays files.

What I want to do is be able to select 1 or multiple rows from this table and pass the first column contents of each row into a function to be able to manipulate.

```
QModelIndexList indexList = ui->filesTable->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
int row;
foreach (QModelIndex index, indexList) {
    row = index.row();
    qDebug() << row;
}
```

I've got this code but this passes the indexes in and I need the contents of the first column of the QTableWidget on the row or rows I select.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What if you check 'if (index.row() == 0)'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of a cell you need to use `QModelIndex::data` method:

```
QModelIndexList indexList = ui->filesTable->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes( );
foreach (QModelIndex index, indexList)
{
  qDebug() << index->data( Qt::DisplayRole );
}
```

You can retrieve more information about selected cells just changing the role. Custom models can accept custom roles.